# NServiceBus 5 Platform installer and WES7 compatibility

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, windows-embedded

Using Windows Embedded Standard 7 the MSMQ feature set comes bundled with AD, HTTP, and Triggers features installed. The new NServiceBus 5 platform installers (powershell) fail to configure MSMQ and warn that these features should be uninstalled.

On this page http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/running-on-windows it warns that these features cause addressing to "not work properly".

Is there a workaround? Or understanding of what might not work correctly? It seems to operate correctly (other than the warnings on install).

Answer (score 2):

Could you uninstall those unwanted features ?

Regarding the reason why those features are problematic, the problem is that when AD feature is enabled the addressing for MSMQ messages is changed and that causes NServiceBus to not deliver messages, and there are no [known workarounds](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/VUl411Axpz0/xKZlZnGRzM4J).

Comment: With WES7 it seems that you have to take the extra features. The MSMQ package itself comes with and doesn't seem to have the ability to configure the features. Embedded 8 broke them into separate packages.